# How to test program compatibility?

Tags: winforms, operating-system, compatibility

I'm using Windows 7 32bit, how I can check if my Windows Form App program is compatible with the following:

1. Windows  7 64bit
2. Windows 10 32bit
3. Windows 10 64bit

Comment: There's no other way to know than actually installing and running it on those platforms. Visual Studio Team Services offers [lab environments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943321.aspx) - if you're on a budget you can always use a Azure trial subscription and create virtual machines as long as your free credits last.

Comment: @Filburt I see, but normally can a 32bit program run on Windows 64bit w/o getting errors?

Comment: A 32bit App *should* always be able to run on Windows 64bit but you *could* access resources in a way that will break on x64 - for ex. hardcode a path to `C:\Program Files` instead of letting the platform handle this for you via `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86`.

Comment: Except for what Filburt wrote, our company never experienced different behaviour between 32 and 64 bit systems, or between Win 7, 8 or 10. Our installed base is several 100.000. However, your mileage may vary, it may depend on how sophisticated your software is.

Comment: @Filburt noted with thanks!

Comment: @HeinzKessler My windows program is really a basic one, btw thanks!

Comment: A more critical aspect is DPI settings. You should absolutely test your application under settings != 100% (96 dpi). Good luck with fixing dpi bugs, dpi and Winforms is a pain in the a**, but that's life...
If your app looks OK under high dpi, but everything is blurred: That's just the beginning. Then read about dpi settings in the app.manifest.